# undefined type of output error in graphql

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql

I write a simple code in graphql server and nodejs with mongodb.I had a data base with 2 collection. Stars and Movies. when I run this query to show me all movies I am getting the following error with my GraphQL NodeJS server:
**"The type of MovieType.year must be Output Type but got: undefined."**

this is my schema :

```
    const {
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLList
} = require("graphql");
const {Movie, User} = require('/home/fateme/imdb_final/db')


const starType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "UserType",
    fields: {
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const starFind = await User.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
            return starFind.name
        }
      },
      imdbId: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const starFind = await User.findOne({ _id: objId._id}) 
            return starFind.imdbId
        }
      }
    }
  });

const movieType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "MovieType",
    fields: {
      title: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const movieFind = await Movie.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
            return movieFind.title
        }
      },
      year: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const movieFind = await Movie.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
            return movieFind.year
        }
      },
      rate: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const movieFind = await Movie.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
            return movieFind.rating
        }
      },
      year: {
        rate: GraphQLInt,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const movieFind = await Movie.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
            return movieFind.year
        }
      },
      director: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        async resolve(objId) {
            const movieFind = await Movie.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
            return movieFind.director
        }
      },
    }
  });


  const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({

        users: {
            type: GraphQLList(starType),
            async resolve() {

              const allStar = await User.find({})
              return  allStar
            }
          },

      movies: {
        type: GraphQLList(movieType),
        async resolve() {

            const allMovie = await Movie.find({})
            console.log(allMovie)
            return  allMovie
          } 
        },
    })
  });

  const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: queryType
  });

  module.exports = schema;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, you haven't defined a type for the `year` field. Instead, you've accidentally added a `rate` field:

```
year: {
    rate: GraphQLInt, // <-- here
    async resolve(objId) {
        const movieFind = await Movie.findOne({ _id: objId._id})
        return movieFind.year
    }
},
```

Just change `rate` to `type` and you'll be good to go :)